# Can not create zope project

Tags: python, ubuntu-10.04, egg, zope3

I'm a zope/python newbee (senior Java programer) and due to inexperience I'm having some troubles starting up.

Im working on Ubuntu 10.4 and I have configured Virtualenv for python. I switched to virtualenv, installed setuptools package and issues this at terminal:

```
(zope3)makcro@makcro-laptop:~/tmp/zope_playground$ zopeproject helloworld
```

and go the following result:

```
Enter user (Name of an initial administrator user): admin
Enter passwd (Password for the initial administrator user): admin
Enter eggs_dir (Location where zc.buildout will look for and place packages) ['/home/makcro/.buildout/eggs']: eggs
Creating directory ./helloworld
Downloading zc.buildout...
Invoking zc.buildout...
While:
  Installing.
  Getting section app.
  Initializing section app.
  Installing recipe zc.recipe.egg.
Error: There is a version conflict.
We already have: setuptools 0.6c11
```

for more verbose result I tried:

```
(zope3)makcro@makcro-laptop:~/tmp/zope_playground$ zopeproject helloworld --verbose
```

which returned:

```
Selected and implied templates:
  zopeproject#zope_deploy  (Paste) deployment of a Zope application
  zopeproject#zope_app     Package that contains a Zope application

Variables:
  egg:      helloworld
  newest:   false
  package:  helloworld
  project:  helloworld
Enter user (Name of an initial administrator user): admin
Enter passwd (Password for the initial administrator user): admin
Enter eggs_dir (Location where zc.buildout will look for and place packages) ['/home/makcro/.buildout/eggs']: eggs
Creating template zope_deploy
Creating directory ./helloworld
  Copying apidoc.zcml to ./helloworld/apidoc.zcml
  Copying buildout.cfg_tmpl to ./helloworld/buildout.cfg
  Copying debug.ini_tmpl to ./helloworld/debug.ini
  Copying deploy.ini_tmpl to ./helloworld/deploy.ini
  Recursing into log
    Creating ./helloworld/log/
    Copying README.txt to ./helloworld/log/README.txt
  Copying site.zcml_tmpl to ./helloworld/site.zcml
  Recursing into var
    Creating ./helloworld/var/
    Copying README.txt to ./helloworld/var/README.txt
  Copying zdaemon.conf to ./helloworld/zdaemon.conf
  Copying zope.conf to ./helloworld/zope.conf
Creating template zope_app
  Copying setup.py_tmpl to ./helloworld/setup.py
  Recursing into src
    Creating ./helloworld/src/
    Recursing into +package+
      Creating ./helloworld/src/helloworld/
      Copying __init__.py to ./helloworld/src/helloworld/__init__.py
      Copying configure.zcml_tmpl to ./helloworld/src/helloworld/configure.zcml
      Copying ftesting.zcml_tmpl to ./helloworld/src/helloworld/ftesting.zcml
      Copying startup.py to ./helloworld/src/helloworld/startup.py
      Copying testing.py to ./helloworld/src/helloworld/testing.py
Running /home/makcro/devel/virt_env/zope3/bin/python setup.py egg_info
Downloading zc.buildout...
Searching for zc.buildout
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/zc.buildout/
Reading http://buildout.org
Best match: zc.buildout 1.5.2
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/z/zc.buildout/zc.buildout-1.5.2.tar.gz#md5=87f7b3f8d13926c806242fd5f6fe36f7
Processing zc.buildout-1.5.2.tar.gz
Running zc.buildout-1.5.2/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-GSG8Wc/zc.buildout-1.5.2/egg-dist-tmp-VVmlKA

Installed /tmp/tmprT0Ycp/zc.buildout-1.5.2-py2.6.egg

Because this distribution was installed --multi-version, before you can
import modules from this package in an application, you will need to
'import pkg_resources' and then use a 'require()' call similar to one of
these examples, in order to select the desired version:

    pkg_resources.require("zc.buildout")  # latest installed version
    pkg_resources.require("zc.buildout==1.5.2")  # this exact version
    pkg_resources.require("zc.buildout>=1.5.2")  # this version or higher

Creating directory '/home/makcro/tmp/zope_playground/helloworld/bin'.
Creating directory '/home/makcro/tmp/zope_playground/helloworld/parts'.
Creating directory '/home/makcro/tmp/zope_playground/helloworld/eggs'.
Creating directory '/home/makcro/tmp/zope_playground/helloworld/develop-eggs'.
Getting distribution for 'setuptools==0.6c9'.
Got setuptools 0.6c9.
Getting distribution for 'zc.buildout==1.1.1'.
Got zc.buildout 1.1.1.
Generated script '/home/makcro/tmp/zope_playground/helloworld/bin/buildout'.
Invoking zc.buildout...
Downloading http://download.zope.org/zope3.4/3.4.0/versions.cfg
While:
  Installing.
  Getting section app.
  Initializing section app.
  Installing recipe zc.recipe.egg.
Error: There is a version conflict.
We already have: setuptools 0.6c11
```

Looks like there is a conflict in setuptools versions 0.6c9 and 0.6c11.. how to resolve this?

Tnx